# JSF File Download - cursor keeps busy as if waiting for response

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have the following JSF download method. Everything works fine: the download box appears and after the file is downloaded to my chosen directory, the cursor on the page keeps busy as if it is waiting for response. Because of that I can't click on any element on the page.

```
public void download()throwsIOException{
    FacesContext con = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ex = con.getExternalContext();
    File file = new File(DIRECTORY_PATH_HERE + FILENAME_BERE);

    ex.responseReset();
    ex.setResponseContentType("application/octet-stream");

    try {
        ex.setResponseContentLength((int)file.length());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }

    ex.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + FILE_NAME + "\"");


    final HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)excon.getResponse();
    ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();

    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file); 
    byte[] buf = new byte[ifs.available()];
    int i = 0;

    while((i = fs.read(buf)) != -1){
        out.write(buf);
    }


    out.flush();
    out.close();
    fs.close();
    fc.responseComplete();
}
```

Comment: can you post the jsf part too

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JSF I highly recommend that you include utility library omnifaces it will make your life easier your example would be something like this

```
public void download() throws IOException {
    Faces.sendFile(file, true);
}
```